# 404 Error When I Rename Store-View Code in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: store-view

This error has been eating my head since 2 days! I have searched the entire internet!

**Scene:**
I have a Magento store (1.7.0.2) with 1 website, 1 store and 2 storeviews.

First store view code is `my_uk_en`

Second store view code is `my_uk_ru`

Everything works fine until I rename (change) the StoreView to something else.

I renamed the storeview code to `my_cz_en`, and frontend gives `404 error`.

I have checked my `index.php` and `.htaccess` files, there is no store called explicitly.

I tried running the new store forecefully by using the following in index.php

```
$mageRunCode = "my_cz_en";
$mageRunType = "store";
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

But still same `404`!
I also ran a search on my entire database with the old storeview code (**my_uk_en**) and there was no matches.

The storeview is assigned to a **CMS homepage** as well. The setting `Add Store Code to URL` is disabled.

**Reindex Done. Cache Disabled**

Inspite of all these I don't understand why I am getting `404 error`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually had the same problem a few days ago. Make sure that:

1. You cleared the cache (as always). :)
2. You have no place in your entire code base which does something like `Mage::app()->getStore('my_uk_en')`. If you have the old store code somewhere in your code base and try to instantiate a store instance with it, it will give you a 404 page (which is a pretty weird behaviour, but that is the way it is)! To find the place where you still use it, you may use somethink like `grep -Ri 'my_uk_en'` from the command line.

Comment: Yeeha! I ran a full search on entire code base. There was a phtml file which had Mage::app()->getStore('my_uk_en') . I renamed it and it worked! Thanks man!!

Comment: You are welcome. Although I always wonder why people accept, but do not upvote answers ;)

Comment: Simon, I don't have the rep to be able to upvote. If you can upvote my other questions/answers, I will get more rep and I will be able to upvote yours.

Comment: Ahhh cheers, mate, I did not know this!